# cloudfront path pattern example for multiple subdomain origins

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

For example, a cloudfront distribution has the following CNAMEs associated with it

```
photo-cdn.example.com
video-cdn.example.com
music-cdn.example.com
```

And it has the following origins associated with it

```
originA: photo.example.com/photocontents
originB: video.example.com/videocontents
originC: music.example.com/musiccontents
```

I would like to be able to GET the following content files via the Cloudfront distribution as mapped below:

```
photo-cdn.example.com/photo.jpg => originA/photo.jpg
photo-cdn.example.com/image.png => originA/image.png

video-cdn.example.com/video.mpg => originB/video.mpg
video-cdn.example.com/movie.avi => originB/poster.jpg

music-cdn.example.com/music.mp3 => originC/music.mp3
music-cdn.example.com/itune.wav => originC/albumart.png
```

What should be the specific path patterns that i need to use to achieve this behavior?

Will the path pattern evaluation happen only on the SUFFIX of the distribution domain path (after `music-cdn.example.com/`)?

Or will the path pattern evaluation INCLUDE the distribution domain path (include `music-cdn.example.com`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you don't have overlapping file types you can use masks like `/*.jpg`, `/*.png`, `/*.mpg` etc.

But it won't work e.g. if you need to fetch .jpg album art from your music-cdn domain.

In this case you might need to split this into 3 different distributions, each having a single CNAME

> ***EDIT:*** read the comments below for further clarification on **which portions** of the CNAME are actually evaluated by the path pattern evaluation

Comment: so you mean, the path pattern evaluation happens only over the suffix of the distribution domain path (after `music-cdn.example.com/`) and the path pattern evaluation does not include the distribution domain path itself (include `music-cdn.example.com/`) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Take a look at the description here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern