# aws cloudfront path pattern for multiple file types

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to create a single behavior for more than one file extension type (e.g. *.html and *.php).  Is there any way to do this with a single behavior?  Separating the two paths with a | or a , isn't accepted.

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500759/cloudfront-path-pattern-example-for-multiple-subdomain-origins

Answer (score 11):

There is not a way to do this with CloudFront.

Each cache behavior only accepts one simple [globbing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))   pattern, with `?` matching exactly 1 character, and `*` matching 0 or more characters.  It isn't a regular expression match.